# Is there a common parent between static mesh and skeletal mesh in Unreal Engine?

Tags: mesh, unreal-engine4

I am creating a struct for my game in Unreal Engine. I was trying to make my struct universal for storing references to static meshes and skeletal meshes. My gut tells me there is a common parent between static mesh and skeletal mesh from there I could cast to the one I am expecting on my particular object(s). My question is if they do have a common parent, what is it? Otherwise, any other possible solutions would be appreciated.

Note: I am referring to the actual Static and Skeletal Mesh Objects **NOT** the Static and Skeletal Mesh Components/Actors

Comment: They both inherit from `UObject`, but so does just about everything. It sounds there might a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, but I'm not exactly clear what that is.

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to have all of my interactable objects dynamically data-driven after packaging from an external database that would essentially just hold paths to these objects. I think perhaps trying to make it look for a `UObject` may work as a band-aid for now anyway.

Comment: I think asset paths are what you're looking for: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Assets/ReferencingAssets/index.html

Comment: Assuming you mean `UStaticMesh`, then yes there's `UObject`. To not allow your struct to refer to anything other than your meshes, you could template your getters and setters, specialize them to work to work for your types and throw a compile time error otherwise. You can also use run time type checking in development builds using the `check` family of macros. As for setting your mesh in the editor, you could just expose two separate `TSubClassOf` variables, or use a `IPropertyTypeCustomization`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UObject

From [StaticMesh.h](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UStaticMesh/index.html):

```cpp
class UStaticMesh : public UObject, public IInterface_CollisionDataProvider, public IInterface_AssetUserData
```

From [SkeletalMesh.h](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UStaticMesh/index.html):

```cpp
class ENGINE_API USkeletalMesh : public UObject, public IInterface_CollisionDataProvider, public IInterface_AssetUserData, public INodeMappingProviderInterface
```

Comment: Thank you, using TScriptInterface<IInterface_CollisionDataProvider> solved my issue!